# $a^2=1$ in a field with positve characteristic

Tags: linear-algebra

If $F$ is a field with positive characteristic why does $a^2=1$ imply $a=\pm 1$. Is it also true for characteristic 0?

Comment: Hint: A polynomial of degree $2$ can have at most two roots, so you just need to think about characteristic $2$.

Comment: @AlexR No, it is not positive characteristic that forces that.

Comment: @AlexR Yes, because it is a field.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So we are already done then, no matter what $\mathrm{char}(F)$ is, or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, stupid me, thanks! Yes no matter what char, as if $x$ is a root of $a^2-1$ then $a-x$ divides $a^2-1$, so max $2$ roots (as $F[X]$ is a ufd).

Comment: @AlexR Right. My hint went the other way. $1$ and $-1$ are clearly roots, and there cannot be more than $2$ (but in characteristic $2$, those are equal, so we need to rule out the existence of another one, which you did in your way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $a^2 = 1 \Leftrightarrow (a+1)(a-1)=a^2-1=0$ now since $F$ is a field, it has no zero-divisors so we can write
$$(a+1)(a-1)=0 \Leftrightarrow a+1=0 \vee a-1=0 \Leftrightarrow a\in\{-1,1\}$$
regardless of its characteristic.

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ lies in an integral domain $R$ (not necessarily a field of whatever characteristic), the equation $a^2=1$ forces $(a-1)(a+1) = 0$. Since $R$ is an integral domain, a product of two non-zero elements must be nonzero. Therefore $a-1=0$ or $a+1 = 0$, which means $a=\pm 1$. Note that this does not assume that $1$ and $-1$ are distinct ; it might be that $1=-1$ and that in fact the only option is $a=1$, as in the case of a field of characteristic $2$. Note that all fields are integral domains.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be an element of a field $k$ such that $x^2 = 1$. This is equivalent to $(x-1)(x+1)=0$, *whatever the characteristic of $k$ may be*. And as $k$ has non non-zero divisors, this is equivalent to $x = 1$ or $x = -1$, or $x = \pm 1$ for brevity. And you have two solutions if and only if the characteristic of $k$ is not $2$, and if it's $2$ you have one solution $1 = -1$.